# SystemUiMode.immersiveSticky mode gets disabled

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-android

I'm using `SystemUiMode.immersiveSticky` in my app, and it works fine, but sometimes it disables, and the system bars pop back up

This happens when focus changes, mainly when a keyboard shows up. When it goes back down, the `SystemUiMode` resets.

Is there a fix for that?

Btw: is there a similar thing for IOS? How do I mess with the IOS status bar?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is quite simple, though im not sure how good of an idea it is...
I basically wrapped my entire app in a gesture detector, and "reminded" the app to be immersive every you tap anywhere on screen.
also removes the keyboard when taps are registered.

code:

```
return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
        SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.immersiveSticky);
      },
      child: ThemeBuilder...
```